# Looping through points in the unit triangle

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a problem where I have two choice variables x1 and x2 which then pin down a third x3 = 1 - x1 - x2.  I would like to loop through various values of [x1, x2, x3].  This code works:

```
w1 = perms([0.1, 0.1, 0.8]);
w2 = perms([0.1, 0.2, 0.7]);
w3 = perms([0.1, 0.3, 0.6]);
w4 = perms([0.1, 0.4, 0.5]);
w5 = perms([0.2, 0.2, 0.6]);
w6 = perms([0.2, 0.3, 0.5]);
w7 = perms([0.2, 0.4, 0.4]);
w8 = perms([0.3, 0.3, 0.4]);

w = [w1; w2; w3; w4; w5; w6; w7; w8];
w = unique(w,'rows');

% loop
for ii = 1:size(w, 1) 
    ... do some stuff with w(ii, :)
```

but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical case for ndgrid

```
[x1,x2]=ndgrid(0.1:0.1:0.8,0.1:0.1:0.8);
x3 = 1-x1-x2;

%I assume from your example that we want x1,x2,x3 in (0,1) OPEN interval, then:
valid_points = x3>0 & x3 <1 

w_prime = [x1(valid_points),x2(valid_points),x3(valid_points)];
```

Comment: `valid_points` only needs to be `x3>0` since `x3` will always be less than or equal to 0.8.